# Use wget to download from a link generated by Chrome

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, wget

I am trying to download some large files from https://commonvoice.mozilla.org/en/datasets to a Linux server using `wget`. The raw links are not provided directly, one has to enter their email address and the browser will then download the files.

My Chrome browser started downloading from this link, denoted `URL`:

```
https://mozilla-common-voice-datasets.s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cv-corpus-4-2019-12-10/en.tar.gz?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3GQRTO3PILORFHK%2F20210115%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210115T130519Z&X-Amz-Expires=43200&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvY
```

so tried the following:

- `wget URL`
- `wget --no-check-certificate --no-proxy URL`
- `wget --user-agent Mozilla/5.0 URL`

and repeat the above with `URL` replaced by `https://mozilla-common-voice-datasets.s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cv-corpus-4-2019-12-10/en.tar.gz`.

None of them works. (`443... failed: Network is unreachable.`)

Could you please tell me how I can download those files using `wget`?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

**Update:**

Doing right-click on the button, copying the link, then using it for `wget` didn't work for me either:

```
wget https://mozilla-common-voice-datasets.s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cv-corpus-4-2019-12-10/en.tar.gz?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3GQRTO3IG5C5BSR%2F20210115%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210115T152745Z&X-Amz-Expires=43200&X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEFAaDDzpL2UNwQHDglPopyKSBIGJHO39vwq2Y2C5st0EfZmCTNtUnPFJojieM6E1aKC16ZcjilXOHZ%2BVkXoYboIarEPZHa7dUFK6d17zEtOFNy0cv7lTDfQ4ZXiOfhEMWf8a5fMdFMtBqcVGZx9GT1rCBI9DPCPeCo7i%2B6qkbEkaYwTKWwilvm69L6rbG7JtWy6gOH%2BGjq4tqSqYdCzCsyYhrCUZVWtH9HW98jvqVxW0dfFF6aTNAMKf9EmT3pMh%2BNvwViTjs5Os1G7UHGIOPq5CUERDjRthIjiAQHMxz68RmXePb5hGawSPHL16T%2BHy4KQkew7SVTQ%2BW6sBqwNWodvEf5sv9ZXOplAUZCzI3uAro2iGDkRfvPqvz7DOuWI88eXuQJCvA4B00szj9hSmDCAVFrr85kZ7H%2BLeeXMHPnLGiO7b%2FP6il0sUWG5M%2BXm%2BLDuf0egPBh5lpThVSscDD05ECqq6Vf5BFbIHs7Yan0MAZRKIqdm9en1crE2Y9%2BlDOz5DAJue7EJFcoKDp2KciDFT8r7BOtuUX7xc18buDXZ226Ypil49kE0MSBfDfQOz54ccj1Dql3UCGn8jycEnJm3Kx7Nk5mrA4WXolRvT%2F5uEEKYPR6i6QbPY8649SErlAoVnzqGdnjynzEq6lJlEcF0ShgcDxLkBGCe%2F6YRobvQOoP0ZU0WNBD7xWIRvc%2FxFvB2YBkaj%2Fuhuk9ycTWPltnyFJqdAKLXOhoAGMiqm5As8rxBOkV3nr5PEcXlv3e%2BLExGw0DpFMgM3Qys8LpSQWRd8IGBIjcE%3D&X-Amz-Signature=ca121bca943ed5c351a93a4d2c81b289335e3bfd447c7597fc4f9749010e7edb&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
[1] 61913
[2] 61914
[3] 61915
-bash: X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3GQRTO3IG5C5BSR%2F20210115%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request: command not found
[4] 61916
-bash: X-Amz-Date=20210115T152745Z: command not found
-bash: X-Amz-Expires=43200: command not found
[5] 61917
[6] 61918
-bash: X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEFAaDDzpL2UNwQHDglPopyKSBIGJHO39vwq2Y2C5st0EfZmCTNtUnPFJojieM6E1aKC16ZcjilXOHZ%2BVkXoYboIarEPZHa7dUFK6d17zEtOFNy0cv7lTDfQ4ZXiOfhEMWf8a5fMdFMtBqcVGZx9GT1rCBI9DPCPeCo7i%2B6qkbEkaYwTKWwilvm69L6rbG7JtWy6gOH%2BGjq4tqSqYdCzCsyYhrCUZVWtH9HW98jvqVxW0dfFF6aTNAMKf9EmT3pMh%2BNvwViTjs5Os1G7UHGIOPq5CUERDjRthIjiAQHMxz68RmXePb5hGawSPHL16T%2BHy4KQkew7SVTQ%2BW6sBqwNWodvEf5sv9ZXOplAUZCzI3uAro2iGDkRfvPqvz7DOuWI88eXuQJCvA4B00szj9hSmDCAVFrr85kZ7H%2BLeeXMHPnLGiO7b%2FP6il0sUWG5M%2BXm%2BLDuf0egPBh5lpThVSscDD05ECqq6Vf5BFbIHs7Yan0MAZRKIqdm9en1crE2Y9%2BlDOz5DAJue7EJFcoKDp2KciDFT8r7BOtuUX7xc18buDXZ226Ypil49kE0MSBfDfQOz54ccj1Dql3UCGn8jycEnJm3Kx7Nk5mrA4WXolRvT%2F5uEEKYPR6i6QbPY8649SErlAoVnzqGdnjynzEq6lJlEcF0ShgcDxLkBGCe%2F6YRobvQOoP0ZU0WNBD7xWIRvc%2FxFvB2YBkaj%2Fuhuk9ycTWPltnyFJqdAKLXOhoAGMiqm5As8rxBOkV3nr5PEcXlv3e%2BLExGw0DpFMgM3Qys8LpSQWRd8IGBIjcE%3D: command not found
-bash: X-Amz-Signature=ca121bca943ed5c351a93a4d2c81b289335e3bfd447c7597fc4f9749010e7edb: command not found
-bash: X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host: command not found
[2]   Exit 127                X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3GQRTO3IG5C5BSR%2F20210115%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request
[3]   Exit 127                X-Amz-Date=20210115T152745Z
[4]   Exit 127                X-Amz-Expires=43200
[5]-  Exit 127                X-Amz-Security-Token=FwoGZXIvYXdzEFAaDDzpL2UNwQHDglPopyKSBIGJHO39vwq2Y2C5st0EfZmCTNtUnPFJojieM6E1aKC16ZcjilXOHZ%2BVkXoYboIarEPZHa7dUFK6d17zEtOFNy0cv7lTDfQ4ZXiOfhEMWf8a5fMdFMtBqcVGZx9GT1rCBI9DPCPeCo7i%2B6qkbEkaYwTKWwilvm69L6rbG7JtWy6gOH%2BGjq4tqSqYdCzCsyYhrCUZVWtH9HW98jvqVxW0dfFF6aTNAMKf9EmT3pMh%2BNvwViTjs5Os1G7UHGIOPq5CUERDjRthIjiAQHMxz68RmXePb5hGawSPHL16T%2BHy4KQkew7SVTQ%2BW6sBqwNWodvEf5sv9ZXOplAUZCzI3uAro2iGDkRfvPqvz7DOuWI88eXuQJCvA4B00szj9hSmDCAVFrr85kZ7H%2BLeeXMHPnLGiO7b%2FP6il0sUWG5M%2BXm%2BLDuf0egPBh5lpThVSscDD05ECqq6Vf5BFbIHs7Yan0MAZRKIqdm9en1crE2Y9%2BlDOz5DAJue7EJFcoKDp2KciDFT8r7BOtuUX7xc18buDXZ226Ypil49kE0MSBfDfQOz54ccj1Dql3UCGn8jycEnJm3Kx7Nk5mrA4WXolRvT%2F5uEEKYPR6i6QbPY8649SErlAoVnzqGdnjynzEq6lJlEcF0ShgcDxLkBGCe%2F6YRobvQOoP0ZU0WNBD7xWIRvc%2FxFvB2YBkaj%2Fuhuk9ycTWPltnyFJqdAKLXOhoAGMiqm5As8rxBOkV3nr5PEcXlv3e%2BLExGw0DpFMgM3Qys8LpSQWRd8IGBIjcE%3D
[6]+  Exit 127                X-Amz-Signature=ca121bca943ed5c351a93a4d2c81b289335e3bfd447c7597fc4f9749010e7edb
[username@host: ~]$ 
Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.1’.
```

Comment: You need to escape the `&` in your updated URL by adding a `\` in front of them.

Comment: @Maurice Ah let me try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update after we've clarified some things.

The URL in question is incomplete, the `X-Amz-SignedHeaders` parameter is missing.

To get a working URL do the following:

1. Add a valid E-Mail address
2. Agree to the terms using the checkboxes
3. **Do not click the Download Button**, instead do a right click -> Copy link address and use that URL in your `wget` command (be sure to escape the ampersands `&` by adding a backslash in front of them).

---

#### Old Answer

What you're seeing is a [presigned URL from Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). This is essentially a **temporary** download-link for a single object (~file) in an S3-Bucket that appears to belong to Mozilla.

The keyword here is temporary. If you use that link before it's expired, you can download the data using `wget` without problems.

You can estimate the expiry time by adding the value of `X-Amz-Expires` to `X-Amz-Date`, in your case the URL had been valid for `43200 / 3600 = 12` hours starting at the specified date. Don't bother changing these values, the whole thing is cryptographically signed, it won't accept it ;-)

So the way you can do that is:

1. Login to the Website
2. Copy the Download Links
3. Download within roughly 12 hours using `wget`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as you can see from the question, I couldn't make `wget` work.

Comment: For some reason when I read the Date value, I read 2020-10 instead of 2021-01, I thought the link was expired... - that works in Chrome? I get an HTTP 400 error `AuthorizationQueryParametersError`.

Comment: Is the URL correct? It seems the `X-Amz-SignedHeaders` header is missing.

Comment: Yes that's the link I copied directly from the Downloads tab of Google Chrome. I generated a new URL right before posting the question to make sure the link is correct.

Comment: And it works for you? (Using it in Chrome again)

Comment: It worked back then but now it no longer works when I clicked on Retry, I guess the URL has expired. But if I generate a new URL, I will encounter the same issue. Have you tried downloading on your side? It just takes 3 seconds to get the link, you'll just need to enter your email address (no registration or login required).

Comment: You don't even need to enter a correct email address I think...

Comment: Don't click on the button, do a right-click, Copy-Link Address and use that one with wget, it works, because it includes the `X-Amz-Signed-headers` parameter - I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sorry I had a phone call. Thanks for the update. Unfortunately that didn't work for me either :( Please see the update in my answer.

Comment: Indeed, replacing `&` in the URL with `\&` works!!! Thank you so much!